# Comparing two different datasets using null deviance

Tags: logistic, entropy

I have two separate datasets, A and B. I have a score that I am applying in both, and I am testing how well that score predicts a disease (present or absent). One property that I think would be interesting to understand is the information content of each cohort based on the cases and controls.

Intuitively I would think that the null deviance of an intercept-only logistic regression model (separate model for each cohort) would essentially provide that value. But I can't find a citation for this. That either suggests that this is not valid intuition, or that people consider another measure more valuable.

Is this intuition accurate? If not, is there another measure that would be more appropriate?

Comment: Please clarify what you mean by "the information content of each cohort based on the cases and controls".

Comment: That is essentially what I am asking: I have a colloquial idea and a guess about how to make that idea mathematically precise, but I'm not sure if there is a better way to represent the idea rigorously. I can expand on the intuition but I can't really expand on the precise question. The intuition has two elements: (1) if the cohort is very small then it contains less information. (2) if the cohort is very imbalanced then it contains less information. I think those are both reflected in deviance of a null model, which is why I proposed that.